# Is it possible to warn the users who left bad comments other than trying to help in a question?

Tags: support, flagging, comments

I see that there are some users who left bad comments in the question when they do not understand what the OP wants to ask.
I hope that the moderators can warn them not to do it again because what they did will discourage the OP from asking new questions.

Comment: What do you mean by bad? When you don't understand it is good to ask

Answer (score 5):

If you believe a comment is rude or offensive, you can flag it.

Hover over the comment and click the Flag <sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub> button to the left of the comment, then select an option and click Flag Comment. A ♦︎ moderator will review the flag and delete/edit the comment as they see appropriate, or if a sufficient number of users flag the comment, it will be deleted automatically.

[image]

If you see persistent rude/offensive comments from a user, flag one of the comments and use the 'other' reason, providing further details. If you wish a moderator to have the ability to comment back on your flag, flag one of the user's posts instead making sure to reference the appropriate comments.

For more information on flagging, see [Privileges - flag posts - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).